# decompiled .class file bytecode version 51.0 (java 7) in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am getting this error when I add a jar and ado 'add as a library', I get this in one of the files in the jar and hence build fails. I am using jdk 1.7.0.

Can anybody help me here understand this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're opening the class files within the left hand navigation window. Find the source code instead (the .java files) and open those instead! Then everything should be normal!